# Packages having unmet dependencies: Broken Packages

Tags: package-management, postgresql

When I try to install `postgresql` i get the following error:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client


Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Breaks: gcc-4.4 (< 4.4.6-4) but 4.4.4-14 ubuntu5 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

How do I resolve this issue to install `postgresql`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 2):

Try removing gcc and install it again:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove gcc g++
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
$ gcc -v
```